# Signing private cert, which key?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I am trying to enable client certificate verification from some php scripts. My server -debian / lighttpd- has a SSL certificate since a while, it works.

It is configured this way :

```
    $SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
      ssl.engine = "enable" 
      ssl.cipher-list = "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH"
      ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/certs/mydomain.net.pem"
      ssl.ca-file = 
         "/etc/lighttpd/certs/my.domain.ca-bundle"
      ssl.dh-file = "/etc/lighttpd/certs/dhparam.pem"
      ssl.ec-curve = "secp384r1"
      ssl.verifyclient.activate = "enable"
      ssl.verifyclient.enforce = "disable"
      ssl.verifyclient.username  = "SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN"
      ssl.verifyclient.depth = 1
      ssl.verifyclient.exportcert = "enable"
    }
```

I tried to follow the pretty good tutorail here
https://gist.github.com/mtigas/952344

Where the difference is that I did not create a ca.key and ca.crt since I already have them configured with my lighttpd (they are signed by Comodo).

Now, my first doubt is what should I use to sign my client.crt?

This is what I did :

```
     openssl genrsa -des3 -out client1.key 2048   
     openssl req -new -key client1.key -out client1.csr
```

Now at this point I need to sign it with the CA, i'd say it is the one identified as ssl.ca-file in the lighttpd.conf, right?

so my.domain.ca-bundle I guess.

Issue is, how do I get a key for it?
I tried to use (-CAkey) the private key I used with the csr used to request the certifcate, but I get X509_check_private_key: key values mismatch

Which one should I use?

Checked a few tutorials and examples, but all of them assume you create your ouw CA

Answer (score 0):

first of all you cannot create your own (CA), a (CA) is a certificate Authority that provides you a ssl certificate. In order to do that you must submit a request, the request basically is a (CSR certificate signing request).After validating your request you'll be able to download your SSL certificate. Next you have to import your ssl certificate on your server where you generated the (CSR). While importing the ssl make sure you choose to import the private key also, at the end of this step you have a .pfx file, to get the private key all you have to do is to convert the .pfx file into a pem file where you can find a .key file that contains the private key.
this article could be helpful: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9834/69/how-can-i-find-the-private-key-for-my-ssl-certificate

**PS:** Note that you should import you ssl certificate on the same server you generated the (CSR) otherwise your ssl certificate will be not attached to any private key, you can use this tool 'DigiCert Utility' to import the ssl certificate, generate the (CSR), test your key...

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to achieve something else. I already went through the whole process and have SSL correctly working on my server. What I wanted to achieve is to authenticate (PHP on the server) a client without asking for username and password, using a certificate instead. I thought I explained it in the first sentence "I am trying to enable client certificate verification from some php scripts", but perhaps I was not clear.